# how to get uiimageview image with subviews in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, subview

I want to implement Advanced image markup in `UIIMageView`. Currently image mark up is working fine.
I'm adding `UIView`(Advanced markup) programatically as a `subview`. So when I save the `UIImageView` image, `SubViews` are not getting saved.

```
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView:self.imageView];


    UIView *rectangle = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectIntegral(CGRectMake(touchLocation.x,
                                                                                touchLocation.y,
                                                                                0,
                                                                                0))];
    rectangle.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    rectangle.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0f;
    rectangle.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
    rectangle.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.0f, 3.0f);
    rectangle.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.4;
    rectangle.layer.shadowRadius = 1.0;
    //rectangle.layer.shadowPath = rectangleShadowPath;

    JSBadgeView *badgeView = [[JSBadgeView alloc] initWithParentView:rectangle alignment:JSBadgeViewAlignmentTopRight];
    badgeView.badgeText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i];
    i = i + 1;
    [self.imageView addSubview:rectangle];
    [self.imageView sendSubviewToBack:rectangle];

     [self saveImage:self.imageView.image WithImgName:@"abc"];
}
```

Following is my Advanced mark up image.

[image]

So how can I save `UIImageView's` image with subviews(Red color dot mark ups)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(self.imageView.frame.size.width, self.imageView.size.height));
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
[self.imageView.layer renderInContext:context];
UIImage *screenShot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

 [self saveImage:screenShot WithImgName:@"abc"];
```

Comment: Is it possible to capture image with AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer? I want to capture image with multiple AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer views. e.g Video Chat like screen.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by taking screenshot of the UIImageView.

```
- (UIImage *)snapshot
{
    UIImage* snapShot = nil;
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(imageView.frame.size);
    {
        [imageView.layer renderInContext: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
        snapShot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    }

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return snapShot;

}
```